# How can I code an URLConnection so that if the URL changes protocols (http->https) the code will keep working?

Tags: android, urlconnection

Sorry for the question title.

I had this app that queried a website's forum and gave a notification if there were new posts on your threads.

The website's owner recently decided to get a SSL certificate, changing the URL from http://www.website.com to http*s*://www.website.com, which made me change that literal in my code. However, I was wondering if I could have avoided this by modifying my code? I've been googling around  Redirects, Protocols, etc, but all the examples I found had one protocol (i.e. http url1 to http url2).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to do anything for that.if server side all certificates are proper chain and all necessary protocols are enable.
look this doc link , what you have to do server side.

https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html

Comment: I'm guessing then that the website owner didn't do things properly, since this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alberovalley.novedadesumbria&hl=es won't notify its users even when they do have new posts :S

Answer (score 0):

no need to change anything when passing from `HTTP` to `HTTPS` or Vice versa, the same code still working